# How to not inherit all variables and methods of an abstract class but only some, in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

I have a C# abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float numberOne = 5f;
    public float numberTwo = 10f;
    public float result;

    public void NumbersAdd()
    {
        result = numberOne + numberTwo;
    }

    public void NumbersMultiply()
    {
        result = numberOne * numberTwo;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is have another class that inherits from this, but only partially, so that it only inherits the `public float result` variable and the `NumbersAdd()` method.

But currently when I create that class with `public class InheritingScript : BaseScript`, it causes it to inherit all methods and variables.

Is there a way to avoid this? I especially want to avoid grabbing all variables, as in my actual project this is hundreds of variables, and it is very clutter-y.

I tried simply creating an instance of the other class to communicate with it, but I am pretty sure I need it in a base/inheritance structure for my project's purpose.

Comment: Split it into two levels of abstract classes, and in some cases only inherit from the lower class?

Comment: Are you meaning having two abstract classes (where abstract class B inherits from abstract class A), and then a third normal class that inherits from abstract class B? 

In that case, how would abstract class B avoid inheriting *everything* from abstract class A?

Comment: No, they mean that the third "normal" class inherits abstract class A, so it then only inherits members of A and not members of B. If you don't want a derived class to inherit members of a class then it can't inherit that class, plain and simple. Think about how `Component` and `Control` work in WinForms. `Control` inherits `Component` and then other classes can inherit `Component` to get only its members or `Control` to get members of both.

Comment: If abstract class `Parent` has methods `Method1` and `Method2` inside of it, and then another abstract class `Child` inherits from `Parent`, could `NormalClass` somehow inherit `Method1` by inheriting from `Child`? Is there a way to make `Child` class locally reference `Method1` so that  `NormalClass` can see it?

Comment: Just move `Method2` into `Child`, then make `NormalClass` inherit from `Parent`

Comment: oh!! That makes sense to me finally. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple stuff. If you inherit a class, you inherit all its members. If you want a derived class to only inherit some members of a base class then there must be some other base class from which only those members are inherited. Your own derived class would inherit the base class with only the members you want to inherit, e.g.

```cs
public abstract class ClassA
{
    public int FieldA;
}

public abstract class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public int FieldB
}

public class ClassC : ClassA
{
    // ...
}
```

If only `ClassB` were declared and had both member fields, `ClassC` inheriting `ClassB` would mean inheriting both fields. By splitting out the members into two classes with one inheriting the other, you can get all members by inheriting `ClassB` or just some members by inheriting `ClassA`. You can do this through as many layers of inheritance as you like.

Consider how controls work in WinForms. The `Panel` class inherits `ScrollableControl`, which inherits `Control`, which inherits `Component`. Other classes may inherit `ScrollableControl` while others might inherit `Control` and others might inherit `Comnponent`, depending on what functionality they need to inherit. This is what makes an inheritance hierarchy a hierarchy.